# Sharepoint hosted apps

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to create a site in my sharepoint hosted app using Javascript client object model in a SP Online site with a custom template.

Question: Can I do this in a sharepoint hosted app? If so please can you provide some examples.

Here is my code

```
this.context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.web = context.get_web();

// Build out the WebCreationInformation for the new site
var wci = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
wci.set_title('My New Web Site 2');
wci.set_description('Description Input');
wci.set_url('mynewwebsite7');
wci.set_language(1033);
wci.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(true);
wci.set_webTemplate('STS#1');

// Create the new web in the client context
this.childWeb = this.web.get_webs().add(wci);
this.context.load(this.web);
this.context.load(this.childWeb);//, 'ServerRelativeUrl', 'Created');

// Now create it on the server
this.context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.createSiteSucceeded),
                      Function.createDelegate(this, this.createSiteFailed));
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.web = context.get_web();

// Build out the WebCreationInformation for the new site
var wci = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
```

You can't write this in your code. You have to load the requestexecutor.js first and then make the client context or the rest API calls to get the desired result. also you have to give full control over site collection in the appmanifest.